# How to set status termination of a process C?

Tags: c, process, signals, kill-process

My program is a rudimental little shell.
It allow you to run programs in PATH as ls, cd..also with arguments.
To run the program type from terminal "./myshell2" then it starts and you can insert how many commands you want.

It starts a child process, runs execvp,it returns and restarts so you can type a new command.
When typed "Q" or "q" all the entire program should terminates.
The problem is that I don't know how to stop it,the code is below.
My idea is, when typed "Q" or "q", to kill the child process created and send a signal to comunicate its bad termination(of child process).
So the final status(from parent) 'll be not 1 and the function returns.
I commented some parts of the code hoping that it's easier to understand.
It works the problem is that to stop it I need of ctrl C.
I would like to say to child process that he must ends with a non-zero value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
while(1)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0) { // child process
        printf("type the command to start (and arguments if required) \n"
            "Q to quit\n");
        char *dest[10]; // allow you to insert
        char line[4096];//commands from terminal
        if (fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin)==0) return 1;
        int i;
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';  
        char *st = line;
        for (i=0; i< 10 && (dest[i]=strsep(&st," "))!=NULL;i++)
            continue;//now you typed the command
        if ( ( memcmp(dest[0],"Q",1)==0 ) // if Q or q the program
             || (memcmp(dest[0],"q",1)==0) ) //must end
        {
            printf("got it!\n");
            if (kill(getpid(),SIGSEGV)==-1) printf("kill error\n");
            //in theory the process should terminates with bad status
            // and the value of the variable "status" 'll be not 0
           // I think that the problem is in this part of the code
        }


        if( strcmp(dest[0]," ")!=0 )
        {
            int res = execvp(dest[0], dest);    
         }
        else
            { int res= execvp(dest[1],dest+1);}

       perror("execvp error");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int status;
    pid_t child = wait(&status);

    if (child == -1) {
        perror("wait error");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (status==1)
        break; //so it can exit from the loop that creates new process
    setenv("WAIT","TRUE",0);                    //dont' worry about
    //perror("setenv error\n");
    if (memcmp("TRUE",getenv("WAIT"),4) == 0 )  //these 6 lines
        printf("WAIT=TRUE\n");
    else if(memcmp("FALSE",getenv("WAIT"),4) == 0 )
        printf("WAIT=FALSE\n");                     
printf("end current process (status=%d, child=%d)\n", WEXITSTATUS(status), son);
 }
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You should read the command line in the parent process, not the child. If they type `q` you return, otherwise you fork and execute the command.

Comment: @Barmar it's a good solution but I need to know if is possible to kill the child and set its termination state to a non-zero value recoverable with wait().

Answer (score 3):

You're printing out `WEXITSTATUS()` for all cases, but that isn't right. You need to check if the status returned by `wait` is an exit status or not using `WIFEXITED()`. If it's non-zero then the child exited normally. Otherwise, you can use `WIFSIGNALED()` to see if the child was terminated and you'll get the signal from `WTERMSIG()`

```
if(WIFEXITED(status))
  {
  printf("end current process (status=%d, child=%d)\n", WEXITSTATUS(status), son);
  }
else if(WIFSIGNALED(status))
  {
  printf("end current process (signal=%d, child=%d)\n", WTERMSIG(status), son);
  }
```

You really should have the parent process handle the inputting of the command and leave the child process to run it though.

Comment: Yes I forgot to handle with WIFEXITED.Thanks it works! You and @Barmar 've right I should handle from the parent but in this case I needed to understand how handle signals in this way. Thank you very much.